# Is $f(x)=\ln(2+\sin(x))$ uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: uniform-continuity

I have to prove that $f(x)=\ln(2+\sin(x))$ is uniformly continuous without the mean value theorem! How can I get a good procedure?

Comment: Are you able to bound its (amplitude of) derivative?  Can you make an argument that this is a useful thing to have done?

Comment: What are you allowed to use? Note that your $f$ is a composition of continuous functions, and periodic.

Comment: I've already proved that the function is uniformly continuous with the mean value theorem but the exercise requires a procedure with some estimates for $|f(x)-f(y)|$ without it. I'm allowed to use the Heine-Cantor theorem and the definitions of the topics involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that any periodic continuous function is uniformly continuous. (Use that continuous with compact domain is uniformly continous)

Comment: Heine-Cantor theorem helps me for a compact domain but how can I extend everything on $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 2):

Hinr: The function is continuous on the closed interval $[0,2\pi]$ and periodic.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the mean value theorem. Verify that $|f'|\le 1$ everywhere, which shows by the MVT that $|f(y)-f(x)|\le |y-x|$ for all $x,y.$